# How do I align these text boxes to be straight and lined up with one another?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textbox, user-experience

I realize this is a dumb question. I'm a bit rusty with my HTML/CSS. I want the text boxes on each side to be lined up with each other and not slightly staggered like they currently are. I know that I am doing multiple things wrong, both in html and CSS, I just am not sure what I need to add/change. I also know that all the boxes except the last one are set to class=leftBoxes when not all of them are on the left, which is confusing.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0x6k94ey/1/). PLEASE NOTE the small preview when you run my code in jsfiddle is not what it looks like when it's full screen. [This is what it looks like full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oNW2.png)

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<body>

 
 <form>
        <label for="son">Sales Order Number:</label>
        <input type="text" class="leftBoxes" id="son" name="son">

        <label for="shipname">Ship to Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="leftBoxes" id="shipname" name="shipname">

        <br>

        <label for="arnum">AR Division Number:</label>
        <input type="text" class="leftBoxes" id="arnum" name="arnum">

        <label for="shipadd1">Ship to Address 1:</label>
        <input type="text" class="leftBoxes" id="shipadd1" name="shipadd2">

        <br>

        <label for="cnum">Customer Number:</label>
        <input type="text" class="leftBoxes" id="cnum" name="cnum">

        <label for="shipadd2">Ship to Address 2:</label>
        <input type="text" class="leftBoxes" id="shipadd2" name="shipadd2">

        <br>

        <label for="custponum">Customer PO Number:</label>
        <input type="text" class="leftBoxes" id="custponum" name="custponum">

        <label for="custponum">Ship to City:</label>
        <input type="text" class="leftBoxes" id="custponum" name="custponum">

        <br>

        <label for="orderdate">Order Date:</label>
        <input type="text" class="leftBoxes" id="orderdate" name="orderdate">

        <label for="shipstate">Ship to State:</label>
        <input type="text" class="leftBoxes" id="shipstate" name="shipstate">

        <br>

        <label  for="shipzip">Ship to Zip Code:</label>
        <input type="text" class="rightBoxes" id="shipzip" name="shipzip">


      </form>
      
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}

.leftBoxes {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 100px;
  
}
.rightBoxes {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a grid can help you out.  See what I did here:

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
}


body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <body>

 
 <form>
        <label for="son">Sales Order Number:</label>
        <input type="text" class="leftBoxes" id="son" name="son">

        <label for="shipname">Ship to Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="leftBoxes" id="shipname" name="shipname">



        <label for="arnum">AR Division Number:</label>
        <input type="text" class="leftBoxes" id="arnum" name="arnum">

        <label for="shipadd1">Ship to Address 1:</label>
        <input type="text" class="leftBoxes" id="shipadd1" name="shipadd2">

       

        <label for="cnum">Customer Number:</label>
        <input type="text" class="leftBoxes" id="cnum" name="cnum">

        <label for="shipadd2">Ship to Address 2:</label>
        <input type="text" class="leftBoxes" id="shipadd2" name="shipadd2">

       

        <label for="custponum">Customer PO Number:</label>
        <input type="text" class="leftBoxes" id="custponum" name="custponum">

        <label for="custponum">Ship to City:</label>
        <input type="text" class="leftBoxes" id="custponum" name="custponum">

        

        <label for="orderdate">Order Date:</label>
        <input type="text" class="leftBoxes" id="orderdate" name="orderdate">

        <label for="shipstate">Ship to State:</label>
        <input type="text" class="leftBoxes" id="shipstate" name="shipstate">

        

        <label  for="shipzip">Ship to Zip Code:</label>
        <input type="text" class="rightBoxes" id="shipzip" name="shipzip">
      </form>
      
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).
Try adding:

```
form{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*NOT a Solution*
But adding

```
[type='text']{  
margin-top:10px; 
}
```

Will make it a little neat.

There's one explanation why the last one is behaving oddly. The text for the text field is taking the text-align center styling, so its displayed right at the center.

It would be interesting if there's any solution to getting the last one to behave!!!